# Why columnDefs is not modified after reordering or hiding in ng-grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, show-hide, ng-grid

**Problem:**

- I am loading the ng-grid with data from a server.
- I am changing the **order** and the **visible columns** in **ng-grid** (using the mouse, not programmaticaly), but the columnDefs is not updated.
- I want to store information about the new order / visibility on another server but I don't know how to access it if columnDefs was not changed.

How can I access programmatically the new order / visibility ?

I tried:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'someData'
    columnDefs : 'columnDefs',
    enableColumnReordering : true,    // this is how I achieve reordering
    showColumnMenu : true,            // this is how I can specify the visible columns
    ...
};
...
$scope.columnDefs = [{
    ...
}];
$scope.$watch('columnDefs', function() {
    console.log('columnDefs was modified !');
}, true);
```

The "columnDefs was modified !" message is:

- printed to the console 2 times (1 time before the populating of ng-grid, 1 time after the populating of ng-grid)
- **not printed** after I manually reorder the columns / change visibility for some columns

Comment: try `gridOptions.$gridScope.columns`, under the hood, it updates this array for sorting, freeze, show/hide etc. i had stored this to save the ng-grid layout

Comment: Thanks ! Your information was very useful.
I solved the problem in this way:
  $scope.$watch('gridOptions.$gridScope.columns', function(newv, oldv){   
   if ( oldv !== newv ) {
    console.dir($scope.gridOptions.$gridScope.columns);
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < $scope.gridOptions.$gridScope.columns.length ; i++ ) {
     console.dir($scope.gridOptions.$gridScope.columns[i].field + " " + $scope.gridOptions.$gridScope.columns[i].visible);
    }
   }
  }, true);
where that if avoids the first operation (there are 2 calls for show/hide column).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `gridOptions.$gridScope.columns`, under the hood, ng-grid updates this array for sorting, freeze, show/hide etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know when a user has reordered a column you can listen to ngGridEventSorted

```
$scope.$on ('ngGridEventSorted', function(event, data){
    alert('reordered');
});
```

Comment: I've just tried it and it works only for sorting (rows reordering).
I want to have access to the new data for reordering and hiding/showing columns.